# correct way to use `getEls` in marko?

Tags: marko

So I'm relatively new to marko and was just trying to follow the docs. I'm building a game with pieces.

```
class {
  onCreate() {
    this.state = {
      pieces: getEls('stack'),
      gameOver: false
    };

  }
}

div#board
  stack color="red"
  stack color="blue"
```

is my code. I am getting a rendering error since 'getEls' is not defined. which is true, I haven't defined it, but [the docs](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codegetelskeycode) have defined it, and even [used it](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#referencing-nested-html-elements-and-components).

I've tried `this.getEls` with same error.

Comment: Read closely: you need a `key` attribute => https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codekeycode

Answer (score 0):

All in all there were 3 problems.

- As pointed out in the comments: [the keys](http://markojs.com/docs/components/#codekeycode) are missing.
- using [`onCreate`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codeoncreateinput-outcode) rather than [`onMount`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codeonmountcode). Wrong lifecycle.
- using [`getEls`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codegetelskeycode) rather than [`getComponents`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codegetcomponentskey--indexcode)

To fix the first one, when declaring my components, I should have a key as in the docs. So:

`stack key="stack[]"` with `[]` as i'm expecting multiple.

The second one is an issue as during the [`onCreate`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codeoncreateinput-outcode) phase, the `el` `els` and other properties are not created, this happens during [`onMount`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codeonmountcode) (as seen in the docs for both methods).

Finally, for my specific problem, I was trying to retrieve components, rather than `HTMLElements`. Using [`getEls`](https://markojs.com/docs/components/#codegetelskeycode) works, but the return is only `HTMLElements` rather than components.

The docs are actually pretty good!